# Whats a DAL Alternative to doctrine for symfony2

Tags: symfony

I really like where *symfony 2* is headed, I just really dont like *doctrine*, I love *codeigniters*  active record db system, is there anyway I can completely remove doctrine from symfony and replace it with a DAL like of codeigniters ?

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2 is a pure [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern implementation. Its advantage over [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is that you don't have to bend your model to a database schema or vice versa. In most cases your model and schema may evolve separately; you'll need to update the mapping metadata only.

Plus you don't have to extend/implement any special classes/interfaces. Your model consists of POPOs (Plain Old PHP Objects) and the mapping is managed by an external object — an entity manager. This allows for good OO design on the PHP side and good schema design on the database side.

So, I suggest you rethink your desire to go back to Active Record. It may take some time for the paradigm shift but it's worth it.

Comment: Doctrine 2 is bulky and slow, i like full control of the queries that are being made. I specifically stated codeigniter active record db. Which isn't really a Active record implementation at all. Its just called that. Well it tried to be but isn't. It just a plain DAL that does exactly what i need it to do, provide a better way to write RAW SQL, but flexible enough that i can write a wrapper for other dbs as well. You didn't answer my question for a non ORM alternative.

Comment: Are you going to use objects on the PHP side and a relational database for their storage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Right, 60% of the project will be in mysql. Everything else is in mongo, but I like php's native mongo class for that so im covered there.

Comment: I asked it because it seems to me that you misunderstand what an ORM is. If you are using objects on the app side and store them in a relational DB, you can't escape ORM — it's not an option. What you can choose is whether to use a prebuilt solution or reinvent the wheel. Read more [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/orm-is-not-a-choice).

Comment: By the way, nothing stops you from using raw SQL in Doctrine.

Comment: Whats a DAL Alternative to doctrine for symfony2? If the answer is none, then thats fine. Ill right my own. DQL is not SQL, and no i wouldn't want to right raw sql. Ill just have to create my own alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that Doctrine is a default choice doesn't mean it's the only one. It's not tightly coupled to Symfony and can be replaced.

Symfony provides sensible defaults but gives you the freedom to change them.

For example, you might [use Propel](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle). It implements Active Record (as opposed to Doctrine2).

You can write your own ORM implementation if you'd like to.

Note that apart from ORM, Doctrine has some useful helper libraries. For example annotation reader is used in Symfony to parse annotations. If you use them you'll need this part of Doctrine.

Comment: Yeah it isn't tightly coupled, so it should be easy to remove. I need a non orm alternative. ORM's are just plain bulky and SLOW. And if not used right, may really hurt your application. Any non orm alternatives??, I goggled but no luck. Now im thinking of just writing my own.